# PHP and Java, how to join them?

Tags: java, php

I'm learning Java programming now, and I wanna use Java classes that I created in my PHP systems. Every tutorial what I found is too old and the links doesn't exist anymore. I tried to use "apt-cache search php-java" in my terminal but no results came (I think this just works for repositories, am I right?).
Does someone have any help?
I use Ubuntu 15.04, php5.6.4, java 1.7.0_85 and my system is 64bits.
Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do this.

Comment: You can use them "together" but what that means is you can use PHP as a web service to pass information to a Java program, such as external DB access for example. You cannot, however, create Java classes in PHP and then access those objects in Java. There's really no need to do this in any case I can think of, either.

Comment: why on earth should you do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed some websites using like this, can not remind now, but I think you can do that through JavaScript . Passing the data to JavaScript and retributive it and again use and send result through JavaScript . [PHP has support for instantiation of Java objects and using them transparently as PHP objects.](http://php.net/manual/en/intro-whatcando.php)
and [Integrate PHP and Java Applications with Oracle WebLogic Server and Zend Server 5.0](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/oracle-java-zend-server-152557.html)

may help you , but truly never did it and having no good knowledge of it.

Comment: I didn't explain in a good way... I discovered what I wanna do is use Java classes in php. I did php-java-bridge installation. Thanks for the help

Comment: what ever happened, if you are able to get your job done correctly, that is great, my best wishes to you.